# Adding a masonry layout to shopify portfolio page

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid, masonry

I've been putting together a portfolio page on a shopify theme I have been developing and I wanted to style the page to have a masonry style grid layout. So far the ways I've been working at it was to use a snippet that holds the jquery portion of code and calling that snippet from my page.portfolio.liquid page. But for some reason I don't see any of the effects of the jQuery and I'm not sure why (i am also new to jQuery)

The liquid code is below:

```
<div id="container" >
{% unless settings.portfolio_collection == blank or collections[settings.portfolio_collection].empty? %}
{% assign collection = collections[settings.portfolio_collection] %}

<ul class="grid clearfix">
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    <li class="masonryImage three-per-row centered">
      <img style="border:1px solid white;" src="{{ product | img_url: 'grande' }}"/>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  {% include 'portfolio-layout.js' %}
</ul>
{%endunless%}
</div>
```

and the snippet code is (based on some other posts i saw on stack overflow):

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    document.write({{ "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js" | script_tag | json }});
    document.write({{ "https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js" | script_tag | json }});
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();<\/script>');
}
</script>

<script>
  $(function(){
    var $container = $('#container');  
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.masonryImage'
    });
  }); 
});
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see any console errors? Can you explain a little bit more what the issues you have with jQuery are? Is it being loaded?

Comment: There are strangely no console errors. I guess more specifically I am confused because no errors are being thrown and the webpage is still being loaded in the same manner as if the jQuery were not there. I was hoping to figure out how to integrate jQuery in shopify/liquid or get confirmation if I was doing it the right way. If you have any suggestions lemme know!

Comment: Hi, Please check that you have not loaded jquery twice.  Or loaded the masonry before the jQuery.  Provide me the test website url so that i can look into it and give you an exact answer to fix this issue.